# Как удалить процесс через питон в убунту?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, ubuntu

Мне нужен модуль для завершении процесса для программмы в Ubuntu. 
`os.tasktill()` мне не подходит, так как он для винды.

Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.kill э?

Comment: os.kill(), для всех платформ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[os.kill()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.kill), работает кроссплатформенно с версии 3.2

> Send signal sig to the process pid. Constants for the specific signals
>   available on the host platform are defined in the signal module.
>
> Windows: The signal.CTRL_C_EVENT and signal.CTRL_BREAK_EVENT signals
>   are special signals which can only be sent to console processes which
>   share a common console window, e.g., some subprocesses. Any other
>   value for sig will cause the process to be unconditionally killed by
>   the TerminateProcess API, and the exit code will be set to sig. The
>   Windows version of kill() additionally takes process handles to be
>   killed.
>
> See also signal.pthread_kill().
>
> New in version 3.2: Windows support.